# Prestashop - Differentiate order whether it is manual or front end order

Tags: php, prestashop, admin, prestashop-1.6

I am started using prestashop 1.6. I want to show in order list (backoffice), whether it is from admin (manual order placed by admin), or frontend (order placed by customer). Is there any way to check this. I don't find any db field to differentiate it. If i missed, please help me to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to check in _cart table by the join of _orders.
recognize orders from BE of two columns:

- id_shop_group
- id_guest

both will be 0 if they come from BE